# setting up android platform for ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ubuntu-14.04

I am using ubuntu 14.04 , I am setiing up ionic on my pc . it throws me the following error after giving the following command

ionic platform add android

Failed to fetch platform android
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/sumeet/.cordova/lib/npm_cache'

Comment: try `sudo` and run in administrator mode. May help.

Comment: @SajibAcharya thanks ! that worked

Comment: good to know it helped. Do accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments section, use the command using `sudo` to give it administrator privileges.

`sudo ionic platform add android`